# Recommendations for a CSV editor (for non-programmers)

Tags: windows, csv

At my company we have a data warehouse which imports some .csv files that are directly supplied by the business side. Some of these are manually created from Excel files, some of them are .csv files where someone has to add a column to, for example, calculate a certain value.

Predictably, it has happened that some people opened the files directly in Excel by double clicking on them and thanks to auto-formatting it lead to import errors. Using import 'From text' in Excel works fine, but it's very prone people not using it. Notepad++ does not lend itself to editing the data.

I know a few good .csv viewers, but are there any good editors out there? I found similar questions, but most of them are fairly old and the suggestions don't even exist any more. Libre Office gets suggested quite a bit, but the comments read as if it's better at Excel at not auto-formatting the data (not a high bar to clear), but not perfect or close to it. OS is Windows.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple text editor for spreadsheet-style data entry](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/7351/simple-text-editor-for-spreadsheet-style-data-entry) I've added a new answer there that seems to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Excel will work mostly perfectly if you use a semicolon (;) as a separation sign instead of a comma (,) or tab (\t).

So if you are able to change the creation process of those files, ask them to use semicolons and you will be fine.

Otherwise LibreOffice is much more convenient with other separators like commas and tabs. Is there sth. specific you have problems with LibreOffice?

Notepad++ and any other text editor will do, too. Just open the file with it (right click on the file and "Open with...") - no text editor will offer to open CSV by default, but you still can open any CSV with any text editor, so feel free to edit them this way. It might be really inconvenient to add columns this way, though (at least if you are not familiar with column editing mode in a text editor like VSCode)

Answer (score 0):

I like Visual Studio Code enhanced with a few extensions, such as the [Rainbow csv](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mechatroner.rainbow-csv) extension.
It works in-browser [(vscode.dev)](https://vscode.dev/), and has a linter (checker) tool built in. Needs some tweaking for larger files.

Perhaps alternatively install the [editcsv](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=janisdd.vscode-edit-csv) extension.